# Calculate the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{x^n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $n>0$ be an integer. Calculate the limit $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{x^n}$$

The limit is of the form $\dfrac{0}{0}$. Using L'Hospital, the derivative of the denominator is $nx^{n-1}$, while the derivative of the numerator is $\dfrac{e^{-\frac1x}}{x^2}$, so that the new fraction is $\dfrac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{nx^{n+1}}$, which is $\dfrac00$ again. It doesn't help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, L'Hôpital fails here. You want $x\to 0^+$. What you can argue is that is is equivalent to showing $$\lim\limits_{t\to +\infty}t^n e^{-t}=0$$ for any $n$. And L'Hôpital works nicely in this case.

Comment: By applying L'Hôpital $n$ times, right? I get $\dfrac{n!}{e^t}$, which has limit $0$. I find it strange that just changing the variable $t=1/x$ has a big effect on how L'Hôpital works.

Comment: @PaulS. Well, as you noted the fact that $x^{-1}$ adds what differentiation takes is what happened.

Comment: Peter: Fair enough.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to rewrite the expression as $\frac{x^{-n}}{e^{1/x}}$, an $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form. The same kind of thing that messed up L'Hopital's rule in the original problem now works in your favor.

Similar to Peter Tamaroff's answer, taking reciprocals made everything better.